# Update Docker tag using Docker task on Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I'm trying to change the tag of a Docker image using a Docker task on an Azure DevOps pipeline, without success.

Consider the following Docker image hosted on an Azure container registry:

[image: Docker image]

My task is configured as follows:

[image: Docker task]

`$(DockerImageName)` value is `agents/standard-linux-docker2:310851`

I'm trying to change the Docker image tag (e.g. to `latest`) but so far I wasn't able to make it work. I've also tried to set the arguments as well, without success.

Task fails with the following error message:

> Error response from daemon: No such image: agents/standard-linux-docker2:310851
>
> /usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1

What am I missing here?

Comment: hm, can you try pulling that image first? mb it doesnt auth before tagging, so fails to find that image

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, could you please elaborate? I'm fairly new to Docker, I'm still trying to understand how things work. Image `agents/standard-linux-docker2:310851` was already pushed to Azure, now I just want to change the tag. The idea is to have different tags per environment, e.g. `latest` would correspond to the Production image.

Comment: add a step with docker pull, before the docker tag step, so it downloads the image locally

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks @4c74356b41

Comment: @4c74356b41 what about the syntax of my push task above? How should I set the arguments?

Comment: according to the web, this shouldnt be needed (pull), you can maybe try just doing docker login as the first step, not sure how Azure Devops behaves in this situation, for push just specify image name, without tag, it **should** push all tags

Comment: @4c74356b41 pushing the image is working fine and the authentication as well, now I just need to find a way to change the tag of an existing image. Hopefully I don't need to pull an image to change its tag

Comment: like i said, try adding a login step before tag, if that doesnt work, add a pull step, that will solve it

Answer (score 1):

Try using Azure CLI Task. Run the following command and select the options in the image.

```
az acr import --name xxxxxacr --source xxxxxacr.azurecr.io/xxx/xxx-api:stage --image xxxxyyyyyyy/yyyyyyyy-api:prod --force
```

[image]